# Does SSRS support formulas in dynamic formatting passed from t-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2014

I am passing dynamic formatting strings from t-SQL to SSRS, e.g.,

```
=Lookup(8,Fields!RowID.Value,Fields!DecLongHdr05.Value,"DataSet1")
```

for the value of the background color in a particular cell of a report

and the value of that field is:

```
iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0,"Red","Silver")
```

I can paste that formatting into a cell's background color field directly and achieve the desired results, and I can pass a single color easily enough and get it to work. Does SSRS not support passing a formula in the way I want it to?

I have a couple of workarounds that I should be able to use in this particular instance, but I'm not sure I'll always be able to do that with other formatting, and I'm wondering if it's not supported or if there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to evaluate expressions stored as text like you want. There's no **EVAL** or similar function.

On another note, if you want to have **Alternating Row Colors**, there are various ways to do it.

A better way is to use **VB Code** so you don't have any of the issues with the RowNumber/Mod workaround.

[How to create Alternative Row Background colors in SSRS for values in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984563/how-to-create-alternative-row-background-colors-in-ssrs-for-values-in-a-group/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's as expected, but appreciated nonetheless. I've used the VB Code in the past, but went the lazy route this time because it's simpler data than some of my other stuff. In any case, it's functioning correctly, even if I thought the EVAL or some such would have been more elegant had it been available.

Comment: If you could calculate the row number in your SQL, you could always use a column for the color with a CASE statement and use the color column. I'm not sure if that's any easier than pasting the code and using the expressions.