# Add alternating row color to SSRS Matrix report with page splits

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I’ve got a Matrix with multiple page splits for each product group. I’m using the below expression to get alternating row color for each product group. The problem is that it works as expected only on page 1. Other pages (i.e page 2) bring back undesired results as per the below screenshot:

Expression:

**=iif(RunningValue(Fields!CurrentIntroducerManager.Value.ToString,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2,"Gainsboro", "White")**

[image]

Comment: Try adding a column to check the expression return value of 
 RunningValue(Fields!CurrentIntroducerManager.Value.ToString,CountDistinct,Nothing)

Comment: Can't you just set the background color property to `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 1, "Gainsboro", "White")`?  Or does that not work?

Comment: Steve-o169 - normally it would work, however, because I've used a matrix with page splits, it wouldn't work. The below method suggested by Hannover Fist worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've had issues with using Running Value occasionally and just use the Alternating Row Color function that someone created a while back.

```
Private bOddRow As Boolean
'*************************************************************************
' -- Display green-bar type color banding in detail rows
' -- Call from BackGroundColor property of all detail row textboxes
' -- Set Toggle True for first item, False for others.
'*************************************************************************
Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, _
         ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean) As String
    If Toggle Then bOddRow = Not bOddRow
    If bOddRow Then
        Return OddColor
    Else
        Return EvenColor
    End If
End Function
```

For the first column that controls the color:

```
=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)
```

For the remaining columns, don't toggle with the third argument:

```
=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)
```

You may need to switch the colors in the first column in a matrix.

[Alternating row color expression in SSRS matrix not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894822/alternating-row-color-expression-in-ssrs-matrix-not-working-correctly/)

[SSRS Alternating Row Colors Within Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045751/ssrs-alternating-row-colors-within-groups)

Comment: Thanks! Your method worked just fine! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions like `RunningValue` have an optional argument to override the scope. In your case, you'll need to reference the correct Row Group within which you are trying to count rows. As opposed to the lowest level of detail which is what it's doing by default. It should look like this, but with your group name:

```
=iif(RunningValue(Fields!CurrentIntroducerManager.Value.ToString,CountDistinct, "MyGroupNameHere") Mod 2,"Gainsboro", "White")
```