# Changing background color on rows while excluding rows that are hidden

Tags: reporting-services

I have an `SSRS` report that has rows background color alternating from white to gray. I also have rows that are hidden. The expression used does not eliminate the hidden rows so that when displayed the report repeats the color where the hidden row is.

The stored procedure I'm using as the dataset has a unique RowNum on it. I'm hiding the row if it has a price = 0. This works fine. When I set this expression on the row in the Tablix : `=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!RowNum.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1, "LightGrey", "White")`, it ignores the fact that is it hidden and the rows before and after as a result are the same.

Exporession for backgroundcolor

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!RowNum.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1, "LightGrey", "White")
```

Is there anyway to fix the expression so that it eliminates the hidden row?

Comment: I also tried this expression in the BackgroundColor: =iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "LightGrey", "White") but its still taking the hidden row into account.

Comment: Can you put into the `IIF` statement `AND price <> 0`?

Comment: Which IIF? the first one? if so where exactly?

Comment: Can't you filter the `Price = 0` out of the table rather than hiding the row? Otherwise you might need the [AlternateRowColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825950/add-alternating-row-color-to-ssrs-matrix-report-with-page-splits) function.

Comment: No. I need the row for a calculation. Just need to hide it.

Comment: Could you modify the `RowNum` field in the query to skip rows where `Price = 0`?  `CASE WHEN Price = 0 THEN 0 ELSE [RowNum logic] END`  Or add a new column that does the same.

Comment: Try... `=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!RowNum.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1 AND Price <> 0, "LightGrey", "White")`

Comment: A variation of @HannoverFist's [AlternateRowColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825950/add-alternating-row-color-to-ssrs-matrix-report-with-page-splits) function where you encapsulate the function body in a `if (Not <HiddenExpression>) Then ...` block would work.