# SSRS Alternating colors in groups

Tags: reporting-services, background, ssrs-2012, alternating

I have tried all the expresssions posted for alternating colors in a group but it's not working correctly.

Here is what my report design looks like:
[image]

I would like each group row to alternate colors and I would like the detail inside each group to alternate.  However, I always get this for the group alternating

[image]

I am using this expression:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!AssignedUnit.Value,COUNT,NOTHING) MOD 2 = 0
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"LIGHTBLUE","SILVER")
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=1,"SILVER","LIGHTBLUE"))
```

for the group fill and this expression for the detail fill:

```
= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "LIGHTBLUE", "SILVER")
```

[image]

can someone help me figure out what I need to change so that the outside groups alternate correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a function to control the background color - it's more reliable than using the ROWNUMBER function in SSRS.

You would add this to the VB Code section (Report Properties --> Code tab):

```
Private bOddRow(10) As Boolean 

Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean, ByVal Type AS INTEGER) As String 

  If Toggle Then bOddRow(Type) = Not bOddRow(Type) 

  If bOddRow(Type) Then 
                Return OddColor 
  Else 
                Return EvenColor 
  End If 

End Function
```

Then call the function from the **BackgroundColor** value:

```
=code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", 1, 1)
```

All the function does is check the bOddRow variable and return the first or second color depending on bOddRow's value.

The third argument is the **Toggle** value. If it is 1, the color will change otherwise it would return the same color. The first column in a group would toggle while the others would have a 0 so the color is the same as the first.

The fourth argument is for the group number. For your report, I would make the inner Group 1 for the last number and the outer group would be 2.

Inner Group First column background color :

```
=code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", 1, 1)
```

Inner Group Other columns background color :

```
=code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", 0, 1)
```

Outer Group First column background color :

```
=code.AlternateColor("MintCream", "WhiteSmoke", 1, 2)
```

Outer Group Other columns background color :

```
=code.AlternateColor("MintCream", "WhiteSmoke", 0, 2)
```

Plagiarized from my previous post:
[How to create Alternative Row Background colors in SSRS for values in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984563/how-to-create-alternative-row-background-colors-in-ssrs-for-values-in-a-group/)

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this technique as well but couldn't find the Code window, thanks for adding that to this post.  I'll give it a try now.

Comment: I'm new to SSRS, and was having trouble with using this method. So I played with a number of combinations to various inputs. For my tablix to accept this code, I ended having to use =code.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 1, 1) in column 1 and then =code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", 0, 1) in column 2 and beyond. Essentially I just had to switch the colors for column 1.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have an item for a row and my columns were year_month.  I wanted to alternate fill color on the column.

```
    =iif(RunningValue(Fields!YearMonth.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2, "PaleTurquoise", "Plum")
```